# Entity framework core closure table (Code First)

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have search out the internet to create a table to support tree data or hierarchy data but it seems not to provide much information.

Let's say I want to have a Location table which can self-referencing if there is a parent by other location data.

How can I achieve the following query in ef-core?

1. List all location item at root (dept = 0)
2. List all location hierarchy. for example..

> - location A
>
>   - location B
>   - location C
> - location D
>
>   - location E
>
>     - location J
>   - location F
>
>     - location K
>     - location L
> - location M

3. List all child location under the selected node and prefer dept level (ex 1, 2, or the rest).
4. List all parent location under the selected node and prefer dept level (ex 1, 2, or the rest).

Here is my Location model...

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public NpgsqlTsVector SearchVector { get; set; }
}
```

Please help or give any suggest resource to start would be nice. I'm new to dotnet core and entity framework.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You desired entity seems to be something like this:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public NpgsqlTsVector SearchVector { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Location Parent { get; set; }
}
```

The `?` for `ParentId` is because your root doesn't have any parents. Therefore, the root (or possibly roots) is the one that does not have any `ParentId` and also other parts of the tree can be determined by their `ParentIds`.

## Update:

Regarding question number two, if you want to read the data with a hierarchy structure, another property is also required to be added to the entity:

```
public virtual List<Location> Children { get; set; }
```

with the following configuration:

```
HasMany(c => c.Children).WithOptional(c => c.Parent).HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
```

Therefore, with the above entity, by simply executing db.Location.toList(); your desired output will be obtained.

Comment: aha, can you guide me at least query number 2 in the question (List all location hierarchy.) base on this model

Comment: Would you please clarify more? What do you precisely mean by location hierarchy? What is the input and the desired output?

Comment: Hey @rad I have update question to show and output example

Comment: By the example, do you mean that the input is a single Location and the output must be all its children and grandchildren and ...?

Comment: Just list out all tree without any input.

Comment: If what matters to you is just the tree to be displayed in view by this output, it doesn't matter whether your output is a multilevel object list or a flat list, because generally frontend takes a flat list (e.g. db.Locations.ToList()) and handles the presentation. Or do you want the multilevel object list for other purposes?